# A system using Java + SQL Server 2014 (How to write a clean and manageable system)

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, architecture, coding-style

I'm currently working on a small project for a tuition centre.
So, I'm actually taking this chance to learn how to write clean and manageable codes as well.

I've setup my database using the SQL Server 2014 and have decided to use Stored Procedures for my operation calls.

What I wish to know are about the Java codes.

What are the best practices to be applied in writing them? How to actually s**eparate the business layers / views / etc.** so that I can partition the codes and **perform my maintenance in an easier manner**?

I need some inputs from a technical perspective. 
Thank you very much :)

Have a nice day guys!

Answer (score 0):

Modularize, object oriented design, service oriented architecture, onion architecture, APIs...  There is a huge list of best-practices/architectures/designs which can help with this.  There is no one-size-fits-all solution.  This question is too broad to even start giving you a specific architectural solution.

Stored procedures do NOT solve these issues, stored procedures are a very specific technology that is appropriate for very specific use cases.  If you do not understand EXACTLY why you need to use stored procedures, you should not be using them.  Parameterize your queries, use prepared statements, use a layered architecture, and use an ORM if you are not a strong SQL developer (maybe even if you are strong)...